# Clang AST: Unused methods of class templates don't appear in AST

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on a source-to-source conversion tool, using Clang's AST via libTooling.

There is one problem which I can't seem to workaround. Consider the following C++ code:

```
template<typename T>
struct s {
    void lazy1() {}
    void lazy2() {} // unused
};

int main() {
    s<int> inst;
    inst.lazy1();
    return 0;
}
```

In Clang's AST, definition of `lazy1()` is fully available (i.e., a CompoundStmt exists as child), while `lazy2()` has no children:

```
[...]
`-ClassTemplateSpecializationDecl 0x7de4a8 <line:1:1, line:5:1> line:2:8 struct s definition
[...]
  |-CXXMethodDecl 0x7de790 <line:3:2, col:16> col:7 used lazy1 'void ()'
  | `-CompoundStmt 0x7de310 <col:15, col:16>
  |-CXXMethodDecl 0x7de840 <line:4:2, col:16> col:7 lazy2 'void ()'
[...]
```

As I understand, Clang only emits method definitions if they are actually *used*. In this example, `lazy2()` is unused and I can't access any definition data in the AST.

I need to access *all* method *definitions* of *all* template specializations.

I am interested in a non-hacky, reliable solution. I am ready to patch Clang, if necessary. I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50581553/3164989) answer on Stackoverflow, however, in my case it doesn't work.